# Getting too much traffic error in javascript for xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, xmlhttprequest, http-status-code-404

I am using xmlhttprequest() in javascript to find the statuscode for the link.

```
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   
xhttp.timeout = 5000;
xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xhttp.send(null);
```

I am writing this code in a function and calling this function in a for loop for almost 1000 links.If i execute this once it is getting executed and then if i launch chrome and trying to run anurl it is showing error like "Too much traffic from the server" and asking for verification.

I have done same in Java but in java(Using `httprequest`) i am not getting any error.

One more issue i am facing is i am getting status code as '0'.What does it mean ??

The speed of execution is also very slow.Is there any way to find the status code of an url faster using javascript???

Comment: why are you calling 1k ajax calls?

Comment: Browsers have a limits of a couple of concurrent xmlhttp requests. So if you set the timeout to only 5 seconds, you can't make 1000 calls in a loop, since the 10th call will have to wait for the 1st to complete etc. Can you explain why you need to call thousands of links in a loop? Maybe there's a better solution that doesn't need so many calls.

Comment: i want to verify all the links for a page @madalin ivascu

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine for xmlhttprequest :

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
   // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", "filename", true);
xhttp.send();
```